# Can't seem to get two divs next to each other

Tags: css

I want the menu icon to stay on the left and my logo to be in the middle, but I want them to be on the same horizontal level.

This is what it looks like now and what I want it to look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVcax.jpg

```css
.topnav a.icon {
  margin-right: 0em;
  margin-top: 0em;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.mobile_logo {
  margin: auto;
  float: middle;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
  <img src="img/s_personal_logo_mobile.png" />
</a>
<div class="mobile_logo">
  <img class="mobile_logo" src="img/s_personal_logo_black.png" width="25%" height="25%" />
</div>
```

Comment: try display inline-block instead of display block and remove the margin auto

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. CSS code without the HTML it applies to, usually doesn’t tell much.

Comment: Note that you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to include a snippet we can run on Stack Overflow.

Comment: `float: middle` - that’s not a thing … you newbies need to stop inventing your own syntax whenever you feel like it, and to stick to what actually exists.

Comment: Added the HTML part

Answer (score 0):

```css
.mobile_logo {
  margin: auto;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <img src="img/s_personal_logo_mobile.png" />
  </a>
  <div class="mobile_logo">
    <img class="mobile_logo" src="img/s_personal_logo_black.png" width="100%" height="25%" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You didn't remove the useless `float:middle` property

Answer (score 0):

With flex you get less css. I have commented out the align-items in the menu class. If you want them to align vertically just uncomment it

```css
.menu{
  display:flex;
  //align-items: center;
}
.menu a{
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">
    <img src="img/s_personal_logo_mobile.png" />
  </a>
  <img src="img/s_personal_logo_black.png" height="60"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Check my answer, flex != less css.

Answer (score 0):

Non-flexbox solution compatible on old browsers:

```css
#img{
width:50%;
display:inline-block;

/*Optional: remove gap between images*/
margin-right:-5px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/h4x1WB2P/0002.jpg" id="img">

<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/h4x1WB2P/0002.jpg" id="img">
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.menu{
  margin-right: 0em;
  margin-top: 0em;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  /*this area needs a set width */
  width: /* set the width */;
}
.menubutton{
  /*this area needs a set width*/
  width: /*set width */;
}

.mobile_logo {

}
```

Placed items into containers to add `display:flex;`. I removed the set width on the "logo.png" so it scales with the height of the `.menu` container.

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
<div class="menubutton">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
  <img src="img/s_personal_logo_mobile.png" />
</a>
</div>
<div class="mobile_logo">
  <img class="mobile_logo" src="img/s_personal_logo_black.png" height="100%" />
</div>
</div>
```